# Python Pandas imputing the string values from another observation

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code, so from `data_current` I need to get to `data_needed`.
I think I have to use `groupby`, smth. like:

```
data_needed=data_current['Code'].fillna(data_current.groupby('animal')['Code'])
```

But it did not really work...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_current=pd.DataFrame({'animal':['rabbit','badger', 'hamster','badger'],'Code':['I-1','I-2','I-3',np.nan]})
data_current

data_needed=pd.DataFrame({'animal':['rabbit','badger', 'hamster','badger'],'Code':['I-1','I-2','I-3','I-2']})
data_needed
```

And by the way, how can I paste i-Python notebook cells / output in Stackoverflow questions, so that everyoneone can see the output directly on this page?

Comment: Is this a typo? Your filled in Code value for badger data_needed is `I-1` rather than `I-2`?

Comment: sure, it has to be I-2 there.

Comment: I posted an answer, I'm assuming that you have duplicate animals where you have `NaN` values? Or is it more complex than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby the 'animal' column and then call `transform` on the 'animal' column can just call `fillna` and pass param `method='ffill'` which will fill any `NaN` values:

```
In [38]:

data_current['code'] = data_current.groupby('animal')['code'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill'))
data_current
Out[38]:
    animal code
0   rabbit  I-1
1   badger  I-2
2  hamster  I-3
3   badger  I-2
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. How do you manage to add the output here?

Comment: I use ipython running in ipython notebook within chrome, you can just use a cursor and select, drag over the cell and paste it, then I select the block of code and hit 'Ctrl+k' to markdown as code

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this for my forthcoming questions :)

Comment: I tried (actually also with my previous question that you've answered in September), it says that I am not reputable enough yet. I will accept once I have enough karma. Sorry...

Comment: Oh wow :) I did it for both of them. I think you don't need that much reputation points to accept an answer. I think it rejected me when I tried to vote then #notthebritestbulb

Comment: oh now I have enough karma to vote and all :) awesome!